# "My Kung Fu is Strong" Trophy is not awarded

Tags: ps3, mortal-kombat-9

I am really annoyed by this as this trophy took 24 hours game play on MK which at 10 minutes a fight stacks up to quite a lot of gaming time...

I finally got everything mastered for smoke and the trophy did not activate. How can this have happened? is it a glitch in the game or with PSN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a list (taken from [playstationtrophies.org](http://www.playstationtrophies.org/forum/mortal-kombat/104221-mortal-kombat-road-map-trophy-guide.html)) what you have to do in order to master a character. You can check the progress in the Necropolis. Maybe something is still missing:

To master one character you need to complete the following objectives:

- 100 wins
- 100 -alities (fatalities and/or babalities)
- 150 X-Ray moves
- 10,000 liters of blood (each character)
- 24 net hours of play

Comment: Thanks for this but I seem to have forgotten to answer this before I think it was something to do with my internet connection that delayed the trophy from coming through it said in the Necropolis that all had been mastered but the trophy was a bit behind.